# Rationalize the denominator of (sqrt(5)-sqrt(7))/(sqrt(3)-sqrt(2))

Tags: discrete-mathematics, rationalising-denominator

No matter how many tutorials I watch, I can't understand how to rationalise a fraction.

Using

${\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{7}}\over {\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}$

as an example, please explain step by step how I would rationalise the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For all numbers $a$ and $b$, we have:
$$(a+b)\cdot(a-b)=a^2-b^2$$
Also a number by divided by itself is $1$ and a number multiplied by $1$ is itself. Now:
$$\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}\cdot 1=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{7}}{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2}}\cdot\dfrac{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2}}=\dfrac{(\sqrt{5}-\sqrt{7})(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})}{(\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{2})(\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{2})}=\dfrac{\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{14}}{\sqrt{3}^2+\sqrt{2}^2}=\dfrac{\sqrt{15}+\sqrt{10}-\sqrt{21}-\sqrt{14}}{5}$$

Comment: Thanks, another example; how would I rationalize the denominator of ${\sqrt{x}-a}\over {\sqrt{x}+b}$ ?

Comment: @RThomP  Hint: $\sqrt{x}+b=\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{b^2}$ Now use the exact same trick.

Comment: So, if I'm understanding correctly: $ {{\sqrt{x}-a}\over{\sqrt{x}+b}} = $

Comment: $ {{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a^2}}\over{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{b^2}}}*{{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{b^2}}\over{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{b^2}}} = $

Comment: $ {\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a^2}} = \sqrt{x}-a $

Comment: @RThomP remember: $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$. So multiply with $\frac{\sqrt{x}-b}{\sqrt{x}-b}$

Comment: Oh, yep, so: $ {{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a^2}}\over{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{b^2}}} * {{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{b^2}}\over{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{b^2}}} = {{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{a^2}}*{\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{b^2}}}\over{{x-b}} $

Comment: @RThomP yes, but you made a mistake with your curly braces I think ;) Also you should use parentheses in the nominator.

Comment: Yep, I'm a student software developer and usually I can get my head around those stupid things (as well as on stackoverflow) but this maths formatting is rubbish to use :)

Comment: No problem. If my answer was helpful, would you consider upvoting? :)

Comment: I've accepted your answer as the solution and upvoted it, but I think because my rep is so low it doesn't display. If you meant upvoting your comment(s), stackexchange isn't displaying the button for me...

Answer (score 1):

Multiply numerator and denominator by $\sqrt3+\sqrt2$

Comment: The OP is asking for a step by step example.